# Regular expression to find and replace ")" in anything matching "pc( * )"?

Tags: regex, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to learn regular expressions to speed up editing my program.

My program has hundreds of references to the 3-dimensional array `pc`. For example, the array elements might be referred to as `pc(i+1,j+1,k)`, `pc(i,j+1,k-1)` or `pc(i,j,k)`. I need a regular expression to search for the ending parenthesis so that I can replace it with "`,1)`". For example, the end goal is to convert `pc(i,j,k)` to `pc(i,j,k,1)`.

I don't need the regular expression to do the actual replacing -- I don't even know if that's possible -- I just need it to find the ending parenthesis so I can replace it.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Here's an excerpt of the code I would be searching through:

`PpPx_ey = 0.5*( FNy(i,j+1,k) *((pc(i,j+1,k)-pc(i-1,j+1,k))/xdiff(i,j,k)+(pc(i+1,j+1,k)-pc(i,j+1,k))/xdiff(i+1,j,k) )+(1.-FNy(i,j+1,k))*((pc(i,j,  k)-pc(i-1,j,  k))/xdiff(i,j,k)+(pc(i+1,j  ,k)-pc(i,j  ,k))/xdiff(i+1,j,k)) )`.

To further clarify: I'm using the Atom notepad, which allows for regular expressions in the CTRL-F command. I want to use the 'replace' option for things that I CTRL-F, but I need to use a literal string for that part. Thus if I can find the ending "`)`" in anything that looks like `pc( )` using a regular expression, I can replace it with "`,1`)".

Comment: How about `pc\(.*?(\))`?

Comment: That correctly finds strings of the form `pc()`, but I just need it to return the ending parenthesis, not the entire string. The expression `pc\(.*?(\))` finds `c(i,j,k,0)` from `pc(i,j,k,0)`, but I need it to return just the `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, actually.

This should do it for you:

```
pc\(.*\)
```

`pc` = literally `pc`
`\(` = escaped `(`
`.*` = anything
`\)` = escaped `)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work because I have, for example, `(pc(i,j+1,k)-pc(i-1,j+1,k))/xdiff(i,j,k)`, which starts with `pc(` and ends with `)`. The expression finds the entire string instead of just the `pc( )` portion. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
(pc\(.*?)\)
```

- `(` - Begins a capture group.
- `pc` - This will match the literal `pc`
- `\(` - Matches the opening parenthesis. The backslash escapes the
  parenthesis, so that it isn't interpretted as the beginning of a
  capture group.
- `.*?` - Will lazily match anything. `.` will match any single
  character. `*` is a quantifier that matches any number (including
  zero) of the preceding element, the `.` in this case. `?` causes the
  preceding quantifier to be lazy, meaning that it will match the
  minimum number of characters possible. This is what prevents matching
  `pc(i,j+1,k)-pc(i-1,j+1,k)` in the string
  `(pc(i,j+1,k)-pc(i-1,j+1,k))/xdiff(i,j,k)` as one match, rather than
  two different matches.
- `)` - Ends the capture group.
- `\)` - Same as `\(`, but matches a closing brace.

The closing brace can be replaced with `,1)` as you mentioned. Everything besides the closing brace is captured. The first capture group is usually referenced in a replace string using `$1` or `\1`. So something like `$1,1)` should replace the closing brace.

Comment: Ah! This would probably work if I was using an actual program to go through my string, but I'm just using my code editor. It allows regular expressions in the CTRL-F box, but not in the replace box. As such, I can't use the (\)). Is there any way to accomplish what I need without using regular expressions in the replace part? (Hopefully my predicament makes sense...)

Comment: @EternusVia Updated my answer. If you can match using regular expressions, you should be able to use the captured groups in your replace string.

Comment: @EternusVia In Notepad++ you can use captured groups using `$1` in the replace string. `$1,1` should do the job

Comment: @EternusVia Make sure you're using my updated answer's regular expression. A previous one I had posted would not work for what you're wanting to do. Just tested in notepad++ using search and replace with regex enabled and it appeared to work

Comment: It's working now with your updated expression. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you a bit!

According to your question, it seems that you want to find all patterns that like `, k + or - number)`, thus `, k+1), k-1), k)` should all be found out and replaced.

I write a regex expression, which should be able to fulfill you, but it's not perfect.

It is like this:

```
import re

s = 'PpPx_ey = 0.5*( FNy(i,j+1,k) *((pc(i,j+1,k)-pc(i-1,j+1,k))/xdiff(i,j,k)+(pc(i+1,j+1,k)-pc(i,j+1,k))/xdiff(i+1, j,k) )+(1.-FNy(i,j+1,k))*((pc(i,j,  k)-pc(i-1,j,  k))/xdiff(i,j,k)+(pc(i+1,j  ,k)-pc(i,j  ,k))/xdiff(i+1,j,k)) )'

print re.findall(',\s*k\s*[\+\-]*\s*\d*\s*\)', s)

com = re.compile(',\s*k\s*[\+\-]*\s*\d*\s*\)')
for i in com.finditer(s):
    print i.start(), i.group()

str_replaced = re.sub(',\s*k\s*[\+\-]*\s*\d*\s*\)', ', 1)', s)
print str_replaced
```

The key regex expression is `,\s*k\s*[\+\-]*\s*\d*\s*\)`, it is not perfect because it will match string like this: `,k+)`, this kind of string may not need to be found out or may be not even exist.

The expression `,\s*k\s*[\+\-]*\s*\d*\s*\)` means: it will match a string: start with `,`, then may or may not have blanks or Tabs, then should have letter `k`, then blanks or not, then may have `+`, or `-` or may not have them at all, then blanks or not, then may have a digit number or not, then blanks or not, then the ending parenthesis `)`.

Check if this will help you.